# std::array c++11 initializer syntax error

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, std, operator-keyword

the  std::array 
im getting

```
no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘myarr = {1, 5, 2, 3, 4}’
```

error when compiling this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    array<int, 5> myarr;
    myarr = {1,5,2,3,4};

    for(auto i : myarr)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but it compiles when i do it on the same line

```
array<int, 5> myarr = {1,5,2,3,4};
```

how to assign values on the seprate line

i need to assign values in the class constructor how can i do it ?

```
class myclass
{
  myclass()
  {
    myarr = {1,2,3,4,5}; /// how to assign it   // it gives errors
  }
};
```

Comment: The answers below work for when you really do need to assign an array after construction, but that is in fact rarely necessary. For constructors, you can and should use initialization list instead of assignment, as stated in the C++ FAQ at http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/init-lists.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of the one pair of braces you need two.

```
myarray = {{1,2,3,4,5}};
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a temporary object.

```
class myclass
{
  myclass()
  {
    myarr = std::array<int,5>{1,2,3,4,5};
  }
};
```

The syntax `var = { values, ... }` is only valid for initializers. But you do an assignment here, not an initialization. What c++11 changed here is that you can do this type of initialization now for any class type (where the appropriate constructor is defined), before it worked only on POD types and arrays.

Comment: "*before it worked only on POD types and arrays*" Not exactly; before it worked only on _aggregate_ types.