# Initializer syntax error does not happen anymore with std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, std

According to the question [std::array c++11 initializer syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314727/stdarray-c11-initializer-syntax-error)
It is not allowed to assign braced  list to std::array in such way:

```
std::array<int, 10> a = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
a = {0}; // error: cannot assign to an array from a braced list
```

But actually I can not reproduce this error anymore.
My GCC version is 4.8.2.
Here is the code:

```
#include <array>

int main() {

   std::array<int, 10> a;

    a = {1};

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and executes without any error.

So, the question is, am I doing something wrong here? Or was there any changes that led to such behavior change?

Comment: The compiler creates a temporary `std::array` object from the braced initializer list, and then assigns that to your `a` variable.

Comment: Yes, it is clear for me. But the question was asked on purpose to understand what has been changed in the implementation and why.

Comment: Nothing, it's just that the compiler have been "fixed". C++ compilers are very complicated programs, and as all non-trivial programs it contains bugs.

Comment: GCC 4.9.2 says that this is C++11 syntaxis and needs to be compiled with `-std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`...

Answer (score 1):

The expression `a = {1};` corresponds to case (10) of copy-list-initialization (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)). So, it should be correct according to the standard.

The problem you encountered may have something to do with the following change from C++11 to C++14: In C++11, when performing aggregate initialization, braces around nested initializer lists may only be elided if the syntax `... = {...}`
 is used, but not `...{...}`. In C++14, the latter is also allowed. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) for details. Now, assume C++11, should `a = {1};` be correct or not? I think the answer depends on how you interpret the standard. Clearly, `{1}` is used to initialize the second operand of `operator=`. Following are two possible explanations that, respectively, give a positive answer and a negative one.

Explanation for a positive answer: The syntax `... = {...}` performs copy-list-init while `...{...}` performs direct-list-init. So, what the standard says is that brace elision is allowed in copy-list-init but not direct-list-init. `a = {1};` performs copy-list-init. So the elision is OK.

Explanation for a negative answer: Just give the standard a literal interpretation. Elision is OK with the appearance of an equal sign, and not otherwise. In `a = {1};`, initialization of the operand of `operator=` is implicit without an equal sign. So, it is not OK. The statement [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) seems to suggest this verbatim explanation.